# ¿Como guardar en la base de datos desde un editor wysiwyg en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, quill

Resulta que habilité un apartado para añadir la descripción de un producto, pero en lugar de ser un simple **textarea** he puesto el editor Quilljs que me entrega un div junto al id donde aparecerá el editor.

```
<div id="editor">
</div>
```

Al no ser un **input** y no tener un name, ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer para recibirlo en el controlador y poder guardar el contenido en la base de datos?

No sirve poner `<textarea id="editor">`, ya que no se ve bien y se desconfigura la página, lo mismo si lo pongo como **hidden**.

Mi controlador recibe desde un **form** el nombre y la descripción del producto (editor).

```
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('pages-add-product') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nameProduct" placeholder="Ej: Arroz">
<div id="editor" name="descriptionProduct" style="height: 300px;">
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controlador:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $newproduct = new Product;

    $newproduct->nameProduct = $request->nameProduct;
    $newproduct->descriptionProduct = $request->descriptionProduct;

    $newproduct->save();

    return back()->with('mensaje', 'Producto agregada');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes igualar un input tipo hidden para que guarde lo que escriban en el edito
prueba de esta manera

```
<div id="quill_editor"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="quill_html" name="name"></input>
```

js codigo

```
<script>
var quill = new Quill('#quill_editor', {
            theme: 'snow'
    });
quill.on('text-change', function(delta, oldDelta, source) {
    document.getElementById("quill_html").value = quill.root.innerHTML;
});
</script>
```